# Scolling with multiple RecyclerViews in Layout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-recyclerview

I have created a layout which has two RecyclerViews. One scrolls horizontally while other scrolls vertically. I can scroll correctly inside each RecyclerView but the page as a whole won't scroll i.e. top RecyclerView stays at top always and bottom one stays at bottom like both are fixed in position.

Following is my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:hint="Search Dramas"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
            android:textColorHint="@color/dark_grey"
            android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border_bottom_background_black"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Most Watched"/>

        <!-- A RecyclerView to display horizontal list -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/featured"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="25dp"
            android:background="@color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border_bottom_backgroundless"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="All Dramas"/>

        <!-- A RecyclerView to display vertical list -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/pick_item"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

[image: How activity looks]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by putting everything inside **ScrollView** and then setting height of vertical RecyclerView manually/programmatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:hint="Search Dramas"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
                android:textColorHint="@color/dark_grey"
                android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/border_bottom_background_black"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Most Watched"/>

            <!-- A RecyclerView to display horizontal list -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/featured"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="240dp"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="25dp"
                android:background="@color/black"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/border_bottom_backgroundless"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="All Dramas"/>

            <!-- A RecyclerView to display list -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/pick_item"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:minHeight="840dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Setting RecyclerView's height programmatically:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new     
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
     ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
// calculate height of RecyclerView based on child count
params.height=1150;
// set height of RecyclerView
recyclerView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Are you losing the RecycleVew optimization, aren't? In other words, the RecycleView will not recycle the views.

Answer (score 5):

RecyclerView only gained (still limited) support for nested scrolling in version 22.2.0 - my first suggestion would be to try that.

The only view that fully supports nested scrolling is [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) (you can see this by noting that it implements both [NestedScrollingChild](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html) and [NestedScrollingParent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingParent.html)) and was added in Support v4 version 22.1.0 (slightly improved in 22.2.0). If you only have a single horizontal `RecyclerView` as the topmost item in your vertical `RecyclerView`, you could instead replace that with a `NestedScrollView` that contains a `LinearLayout` with your horizontal `RecyclerView` followed by your vertical `RecyclerView`.

Comment: I used three recycler view in one layout and in a scroll view. my recycler view items in 2nd recycler view getting scrolled. and i wanted to show all the items without scrolling. but got success with NestedScrollView. thanks