# Scroll not working in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have RecyclerView and LinearLayout in CoordinatorLayout. For RecyclerView  scroll is working fine but i want above content to scroll in the screen. Please guide what changes i need to do or anything im doing wrong please guide me.

my activity_article_polls.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="in.passionconnect.application.ArticlePolls">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/landing_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="440dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_article_polls" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and my content_article_polls.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="in.passionconnect.application.ArticlePolls"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_article_polls">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/landing_list"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_filters"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:weightSum="3">


                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/chk_date"
                    style="@style/roboregular"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:buttonTint="#ffffff"
                    android:text="Newest"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/chk_random"
                    style="@style/roboregular"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:buttonTint="#ffffff"
                    android:text="Random"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/chk_popular"
                    style="@style/roboregular"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:buttonTint="#ffffff"
                    android:text="Popularity"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/card_summary_read_more_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/card_background_gradient_overlay"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/landing_card_imageview_height"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/card_gradient_overlay"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/article_poll_title"
                        style="@style/robobold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Top 3 Highest Grossing Hollywood Movies"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp">

                        <in.passionconnect.application.view.RoundedImageView
                            android:id="@+id/card_author_icon"
                            android:layout_width="40dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:padding="12dp"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/lion" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/article_author"
                                style="@style/robobold"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ems="8"
                                android:text="Prasanth"
                                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                                android:textSize="15sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/article_author_desn"
                                style="@style/roboregular"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="developer at varchas technologies"
                                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/article_date"
                                style="@style/roboregular"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="12th March 2016 06:09:06 PM"
                                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/article_author_id"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                            android:visibility="invisible" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/article_title_id"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                            android:visibility="invisible" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_follow"
                        style="@style/robobold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/follow_border"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Follow"
                        android:textColor="#b7492b"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_unfollow"
                        style="@style/robobold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/follow_border"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Following"
                        android:textColor="#b7492b"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/card_summary"
                    style="@style/roboregular"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="2.5dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/card_summary"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/landing_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I have tried like also, only my recyclerview scroll. I want scroll the whole screen along with the recyclerview.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: use NestedScrollView  as parent for your recyclerview and linearlayout

Comment: Are you trying to do this https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: If you want both recyclerview and your included layout both to be scrollable, you can try below code.

Comment: @Drv i tried your coding its not working, my recyclerview hides, i cant able see my recyclerview.

Comment: @SaravInfern i tried using NestedScrollView after only i came to SO, its not working

Comment: I think you need to give a fixed height to your recyclerview and it might work fine.

Comment: @Mani no im not using CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: @MakeitSimple Then you should try with `NestedScrollView`. If it's not working, you've to find out the issue. Coordinator layout alone won't work for scrolling the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atlast i tried and fixed the scrolling problem. I have referred [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30903390/scolling-with-multiple-recyclerviews-in-layout)

Just setting the height to my Recyclerview `android:minHeight="840dp"`

content_article_polls.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="in.passionconnect.application.ArticlePolls"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_article_polls">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/landing_list"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_filters"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:weightSum="3">


                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/chk_date"
                    style="@style/roboregular"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:buttonTint="#ffffff"
                    android:text="Newest"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/chk_random"
                    style="@style/roboregular"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:buttonTint="#ffffff"
                    android:text="Random"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/chk_popular"
                    style="@style/roboregular"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:buttonTint="#ffffff"
                    android:text="Popularity"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/card_summary_read_more_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/card_background_gradient_overlay"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/landing_card_imageview_height"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/card_gradient_overlay"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/article_poll_title"
                        style="@style/robobold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Top 3 Highest Grossing Hollywood Movies"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp">

                        <in.passionconnect.application.view.RoundedImageView
                            android:id="@+id/card_author_icon"
                            android:layout_width="40dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:padding="12dp"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/lion" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/article_author"
                                style="@style/robobold"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ems="8"
                                android:text="Prasanth"
                                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                                android:textSize="15sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/article_author_desn"
                                style="@style/roboregular"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="developer at varchas technologies"
                                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/article_date"
                                style="@style/roboregular"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="12th March 2016 06:09:06 PM"
                                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/article_author_id"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                            android:visibility="invisible" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/article_title_id"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                            android:visibility="invisible" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_follow"
                        style="@style/robobold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/follow_border"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Follow"
                        android:textColor="#b7492b"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_unfollow"
                        style="@style/robobold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/follow_border"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Following"
                        android:textColor="#b7492b"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/card_summary"
                    style="@style/roboregular"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="2.5dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/card_summary"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/landing_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:minHeight="840dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Why 840dp? Not any other value?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="in.passionconnect.application.ArticlePolls">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_article_polls" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And your other layout to be included should look as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="in.passionconnect.application.ArticlePolls"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/landing_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="440dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/landing_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_filters"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chk_date"
            style="@style/roboregular"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:buttonTint="#ffffff"
            android:text="Newest"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chk_random"
            style="@style/roboregular"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:buttonTint="#ffffff"
            android:text="Random"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chk_popular"
            style="@style/roboregular"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:buttonTint="#ffffff"
            android:text="Popularity"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/card_summary_read_more_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card_background_gradient_overlay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/landing_card_imageview_height"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/card_gradient_overlay"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article_poll_title"
                style="@style/robobold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Top 3 Highest Grossing Hollywood Movies"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp">

                <in.passionconnect.application.view.RoundedImageView
                    android:id="@+id/card_author_icon"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/lion" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/article_author"
                        style="@style/robobold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="8"
                        android:text="Author name"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/article_author_desn"
                        style="@style/roboregular"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="author"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/article_date"
                        style="@style/roboregular"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="12th March 2016 06:09:06 PM"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_follow"
                style="@style/robobold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/follow_border"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Follow"
                android:textColor="#b7492b"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: recyclerview hides, i cant able to see

Comment: i implemented your code, still its not working. I have tried in many ways, only recyclerview is scrolling not above part

Comment: Please paste your whole layout so that I can understand what do you want to scroll above recyclerview.

Comment: Ok let me try.Wait for sometime.

Comment: @MakeitSimple Please check my edited answer of activity_article_polls.xml, where I've just removed one line and check if it works. And your recyclerview's list must be bigger so that everything is crollable,else if recyclerview's height is small, there is no need of scroll so it may not scroll.

Comment: I have tried yours edited answer, its not working. I fixed that i update my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and idea and guided me.

Comment: @Make it Simple That was the thing I mentioned in last comment, that it is so obvious that recyclerview's height must be larger else how can other screens scroll if its is not going offscreen.BTW its good that u got your answer.:)